# Make the div show depending on the options selected in both select tags

Tags: javascript, css

[pic of code code was not available on this computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDaVK.png)

sorry for the picture i codes on my other computer i need to find away so that the div appears depending on a combination of options from both selects if anyone can help that would be great

Comment: Create a snippet with this code so it can be tested and debugged.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I understood that, U need a div which is toggled based on the value which is selected in the select element. Is this correct? @Sean

Comment: yes but with two select element so if they if they select so with if theres two select tags the first one have option 1,2,3,4 and the second having options a,b,c,d. so if they select a in one and 4 in the other it would show a certain div  with a different answer for every combination

Comment: @SeanReed-Forrester I provided One JSFiddle and code in the answer. Can you look once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the combination of two select values selected you want to show the div or hide.

You can get the selected value for select using

```
document.getElementById("getFname").value
```

Compare two select values and apply the styling depending on it rather than sending this param in onchange.

Check code @ http://jsbin.com/nahiko/edit?html,console,output

Comment: not quite because this only works if there the same value so for instance for every combination they could put between the two selects a different show result will incur

Comment: Ya you can add different combinations for showing values. Right now I have just given one scenario

Comment: Cold you give me an example it would be helpful if you could as eventually we will have a div show for each combination they could input

Comment: if(firstSelectOutput =("4")) && secondSelectOutput =("1") ) should this work

Comment: yes. Updated jsfiddle . You can check once. In the similar way you can make conditions to show and hide. You can also refactor some code. Try using angular js your code will be minizied, and show, hide flags can be used. In few lines of code would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Two selections Hiding and display one DIV.

```
<select id="selection"> 
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>
<select id="selection2">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<div name="toggle"  id="One" style="display:none">
   U can see me, if you select option ONE
</div>

<div name="toggle" id="Two" style="display:none">
  U can see me, if you select option TWO
</div>

 var _selectEle = document.getElementById('selection');

  function toggleDivs(evt){
    var old = document.querySelector('.show') || false;
   if(old){
    old.className = ''
   }
   if(!this.value){
     return;
   }
   if(_selectEle2.value == "A" && _selectEle1.value == "One"){
     document.getElementById("One").className = 'show';
   }
   else if(_selectEle2.value == "B" && _selectEle1.value == "Two"){
     document.getElementById("Two").className = 'show';
   }
 }

 _selectEle1.addEventListener('change', toggleDivs);
 _selectEle2.addEventListener('change', toggleDivs);
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjv9no45/1/)